# HTML5 with swf and .net

Tags: c#, html, flash, html5-video, adobe-animate

1. I have some confusion about HTML5. Why do people want to to convert
   swf to HTML5 - what is benefit or drawback of using swf?

   2. What are best way to convert swf, I have checked some tools like
      Adobe Animate CC but it seems that it does not work for all swf - so
      what are the actual limitations or any other tool that can do magic?
   3. Is it bad practice to use swf with HTML5?
   4. Is it correct to use Asp.Net with HTML5 or you see some drawback? I know that we need to use at least one type of script for backend

Thanks

Comment: SWF, on the web, needs a browser plugin (Flash Player) to work. Browser plugins is something that is being phased out by major browsers. After 2020, SWF will only work inside native applications (PC, Mac, Android, iOS) but not inside major browser brands.

Comment: Yes, this is what we are preparing for 2020. We have a website with 500+ interactive movies written in Actionscript 1.0 and website is asp.net; we are trying to find out quick way to get all working even after 2020.

Comment: After 2020 your visitors will have to find a desktop or mobile browser app that chooses to still support swf. You could try using Animate CC (using AS3 code and AIR) to make a viewer app for both desktop and mobile. Use its browser API `stageWebView` to load the website URL and it might display ("might" is because I never tested any AS1-based swf). All you can do is try...

Comment: PS: This [example AIR/AS3 code](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_stage_web_view.html) loads Google.com. If you modify it to load your website and it works well, then you'll know if worth offering a custom-made viewer app to your users. Alternatively just invest in paying a coder(s) to recreate the interactivity using HTML5/Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are some performance benefits on desktop devices, but SWFs are usually much slower on modern mobile devices, and are unsupported by iOS devices. The biggest reason you should not use SWFs, is they are usually executed by Flash Player which is [being retired](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/) by Adobe in 2020 and they are already partially blocked by some browsers such as Chrome.
2. Realistically for any non-trivial application, you need to entirely rewrite a SWF in HTML5. You may be able to use some of the ActionScript code in JavaScript as these languages are similar due to them both being implementations of [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).
3. See point 1. You can do it, but it's not a good idea.
4. It's neither correct nor incorrect. It's an option. And a viable one. But there are many other backend alternative languages including (but in no way limited to) Ruby, Java, F#, JavaScript etc.